# How do i remove an outer div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok so i have this structure

```
 <div class="field_with_errors">
    <input id="count" name="count" size="2" type="text" />
    <label class="message" for="count_for">Required</label>
 </div>
```

How do i remove the outer `field_with_errors` and the inner message and just leave the input tag

if I do

```
$("#count").closest(".field_with_errors").remove()
```

it removes the entire div

I can remove the inner `.message` first but not sure how to remove the outer

```
$("#count").closest(".field_with_errors").find('.message').remove()
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 8):

use `replacewith()` method,

```
$(".field_with_errors").replaceWith($("#count"));​
```

[here is the fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/4/)

Answer (score 5):

you can use `replaceWith()` method:

```
$('.field_with_errors').replaceWith($("#count"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mgy9W/